# Union All while prioritizing the first table if the second table have same column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with similar column, and i want to join them so i can sort them out together.

```
select * from (
        (select * from table_1) 
        union all
        (select * from table_2 )
       ) t order by id column_1;
```

[image: table_1]

And

[image: table_2]

Result

[image: result]

How do I show table_1 row only when there's already a duplicate in table_2, like this  ?

[image: result_2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` in the `where` clause when you select from `table_2`:

```
select * from table_1
union all
select t2.* from table_2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table_1 t1 where t1.colum_1 = t2.colum_1)
order by colum_1
```

There is no need for subqueries.
The `order by` clause operates on the result of the `union`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=478bdd5d7b2b71e43c39c2fa933f233c).
Results:

```
> colum_1 | column_2
> :------ | -------:
> A       |        1
> B       |        1
> C       |        1
> D       |        2
> E       |        2
```